# How would I refactor this code to be more object-oriented?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, refactoring

### UPDATE

So I followed the advice of '[justkt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234309/how-would-i-refactor-this-code-to-be-more-object-oriented/5234433#5234433)' and '[xtofl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234309/how-would-i-refactor-this-code-to-be-more-object-oriented/5234495#5234495)' and made some huge changes to my code. I think this is a better design, but please still provide feedback and suggestions for improvements.

Firstly, I created some enumerations...

```
var SymbolName = {
    alpha : 0,
    beta : 1,
    // ... etc...
};
Object.freeze(SymbolName);

var TypeOfSymbol = {
    GreekSymbol : 0,
    // ... etc...
};
Object.freeze(TypeOfSymbol);
```

... then I refactored my `Symbol` class by taking out all of the member variables I had previously and making it into an object that remembers 4 values per `Symbol`...

```
function Symbol(name, id, value, type) {

    var name = name;
    var id = id;
    var value = value;
    var type = type;

    this.getName = function() {
        return name;
    };

    this.getID = function() {

        return id;
    };

    this.getValue = function() {

        return value;
    };

    this.getMathMLTag = function() {

        var tag;
        switch (Number(type)) {

            case TypeOfSymbol.GreekSymbol:

                tag = 'mi';
                break;

            default:

                tag = 'mo';
                break;
        }
        return tag; 
    };
};
```

Now, to create and access these `Symbol` objects, I created a `Symbols` object that has an array of all possible `Symbol` objects...

```
function Symbols() {

    var theSymbols = new Array();

    // new Symbol(name, id, value, type)
    theSymbols[SymbolName.alpha] = new Symbol('alpha', 'symbol_' + SymbolName.alpha, '&#x03B1;', TypeOfSymbol.GreekSymbol);
    // ... etc...

    this.getSymbol = function(symbolID) {

        return theSymbols[symbolID];
    };
};
```

So now everything is easy. I declare a variable `var symbols = new Symbols();` and if I want to get symbols, I can just do:

```
symbols.getSymbol(SymbolName.alpha); // get the Symbol object
symbols.getSymbol(SymbolName.alpha).getValue(); // get the Symbol value
symbols.getSymbol(SymbolName.alpha).getID(); // get the Symbol ID
```

This easily allows me to create the `<div>`s for each `Symbol` easily:

```
$.fn.AppendGreekSymbols = function() {
    var symbol;
    var mathTag;
    var openingTags;
    var closingTags;

    // lower-case Greek Alphabet
    var index = SymbolRanges.GreekSymbolsStartIndex;

    for (index; index <= SymbolRanges.GreekSymbolsEndIndex; index++) {

        symbol = symbols.getSymbol(index);

        openingTags = '<div id=\"' + symbol.getID() + '\" class=\"symbol ' + symbol.getName() + '\">';
        mathTag = '<math display=\"block\"><' + symbol.getMathMLTag() + '>';
        closingTags = '</' + symbol.getMathMLTag() + '></math></div>';

        $('.greek-symbols').append(openingTags + mathTag + symbol.getValue() + closingTags);
    }
};
```

Also, I can define 1 click handler for all `Symbol` objects easily:

```
$(function() {

    $('div.symbol').click(function() {

        var targetSymbolID = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
        var symbol = symbols.getSymbol(targetSymbolID);
        $().InsertSymbol(symbol);
    });
});
```

... and that's it! Yay! I think this was a great change... I feel very proud of this refactoring process and the design I came up with. What do you guys think?

### Original Post

I have a `Symbol` class that looks something like this:

```
function Symbol() {
    // I need to define some functions in here  
};
Symbol.prototype.alpha = "&#x03B1;";
Symbol.prototype.Alpha = "A";
Symbol.prototype.beta = "&#x03B2;";
Symbol.prototype.Beta = "B";
Symbol.prototype.gamma = "&#x03B3;";
Symbol.prototype.Gamma = "&#x0393;";
Symbol.prototype.delta = "&#x03B4;";
Symbol.prototype.Delta = "&#x0394;";
... and so on for nearly 500 symbols...
```

Each symbol will individually be put in it's own `<div class="symbol alpha">` element, but `alpha` would be a class name corresponding to the symbol name... so there are other elements like this, such as `<div class="symbol beta">`, `<div class="symbol gamma">`, etc... So to do this, I would have a lot of repetitive code:

```
var symbol = new Symbol();
$('.greek-symbols').append('<div class="symbol alpha">' + symbol.alpha + '</div>');
$('.greek-symbols').append('<div class="symbol beta">' + symbol.beta + '</div>');
$('.greek-symbols').append('<div class="symbol gamma">' + symbol.gamma + '</div>');
... etc...
```

Now, what I want to do is set up a click event handler for each symbol and its corresponding `<div>` container. Again, I would have a lot of repetitive code, like so:

```
$('div.symbol.alpha').click(function() {

    $().InsertSymbol(symbol.alpha);
});
$('div.symbol.beta').click(function() {

    $().InsertSymbol(symbol.beta);
});
... and so on...
```

I'm thinking there is a better way to do this. Ideally, I would like to have only one event handler that would parse out the symbol name from the class, look it up in the `Symbol` class, and do work that way. So...

```
$('div.symbol').click(function() {

    // I know the following code doesn't correctly parse out the correct class,
    // I'll worry about that later, but the idea is clear
    var symbolName = $(this).attr('class'); // parse out the correct class, the symbol name
    $().InsertSymbol(Symbol.getSymbol(symbolName));
});
```

... and in the `Symbol` class, I would have this `getSymbol()` function that would take a name and look up the symbol and return the correct one. However, I'm not sure how to do this in JavaScript/jQuery. How would I set up this logic? I don't know if JavaScript has a HashMap class, like the way Java has, so what would be a good way to look up these symbols?

Let me know if I need to clarify further.

**p.s. I welcome any suggestions on sources/references for good object-oriented design**

Comment: Why are you storing the symbols in the prototype? Why don't you use a plain object and add each symbol like obj['alpha']?

Comment: I don't know haha... I don't think I understand OO design in JavaScript very well, which is why I'm asking how to refactor this. I'm sure there are better ways to do this so I was hoping for people to point out flaws.

Comment: Although this certainly has a lot of OO concepts in it, it looks a bit over-engineered to me.  Why accessors if you can have member variables?  Why the `symbols.get(Symbols.alfa)` roundtrip if you could define `var alfa = new Symbol...`?  (thanks for mentioning me:)

Comment: You're welcome and thank you for the help. Now, I thought you were telling me to NOT have member variables, but instances of an object? I was going off of that advice. The reason for the indirect access is because I need all of my `Symbol`s available at any given time; I have over 500 of them. So I have the wrapper class `Symbols` that will be instantiated once and will be "global" to the whole page. My project is a lot more than just writing good OO code regarding these symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may benefit from an object oriented approach:
if you define a `Symbol` class, it would probably have a lot of *instances*, not *member variables*.

Note: code is yet untested - grab the idea.

EDIT: jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/xtofl/ttjZw/4/

```
// the class:
function Symbol( name, lowname, upcase, lowcase ) {
   this.name = name;
   this.lowname = lowname;
   this.upcase=upcase;
   this.lowcase=lowcase;
}
// creates a div - may be done using jQuery DOM functions
Symbol.prototype.makedivs = function() {
   return "<div class='"+this->name+"'>"+this.upcase+"</div>"
         +"<div class='"+this->lowname+"'>"+this.lowcase+"</div>"
}
Symbol.prototype.addhandler = function() {
   var symbol = this;
   $(this->name).click()( function(e){ document.write( symbol->upcase ); } );
}



$(document).ready( function() {

  // the instances:
  var symbols = [
    new Symbol( 'alfa', 'Alfa', "&#x03B1;", "&#x03B1;" ),
    new Symbol( 'beta', 'Beta', "&#x03B1;", "&#x03B1;" ),
    //...
  ];
  for( var i = 0; i != symbols.length; ++i ) {
    symbols[i].addhandler();  
  }

});
```

Comment: Sorry? I haven't taken a class on OO design, nor have I taken a class on JavaScript. I like your suggestion though and it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @xtofl... not a problem. I wish the whole world is object oriented as well. That said, I'm still a student :) so I'm still learning. Want to point me to good sources/references for good OO design, both for the web and non-web worlds?

Comment: @Hristo: I think it's a nice project, but too much code for the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript has what are sometimes called [associative arrays](http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/) but most commonly in Javascript [object literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831181/javascript-associative-array/3831209#3831209).  Below the object literal "values" holds your keys (class names) and values (symbols).

```
function Symbol() {
    // I need to define some functions in here  
};
Symbol.prototype.values = {
    alpha: "&#x03B1;",
    beta: "&#x03B2;",
    gamma: "&#x03B3;",
    // ...and so on

};
```

Or you can do it like:

```
function Symbol() {
    // I need to define some functions in here  
};
Symbol["alpha"] = "&#x03B1;";
Symbol["beta"] = "&#x03B2;";
Symbol["gamma"] = "&#x03B3;";
// ...and so on
```

Rather than having your divs have a class of "symbol SYMBOLNAME" such as "symbol alpha", I would suggest having a class of symbol and an id of SYMBOLNAME such as alpha.  This only works, of course, if your symbols are unique for the page.  Given that, this is how you would retrieve the value:

```
$('div.symbol').click(function() {
    var symbolName = this.id; // get the symbol name from the ID
    $().InsertSymbol(Symbol.values[symbolName]);
    // or in case of the second option, $().InsertSymbol(Symbol.[symbolName]);
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('class');` would print out both classes including the symbol class `symbol alpha` as his div is multiple classed

Comment: He doesn't even need to change the prototype definitions he has, since  `Symbol` itself is just an object and he can access the values directly from the existing prototypes, like so: `Symbol[symbolName]`

Comment: @Val - this is correct, I had not changed that from the original provided code.  I have updated my answer to suggest using the ID.

Comment: You should also look at using #delegate instead of #click, as it seems you're going to have a ton of handlers on the page.

Comment: @justkt where is my +1 then lol only joking good idea non the less best for the answer I think

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the suggestion. I like the idea of setting the ID to the unique symbol name even better. Are IDs case-sensitive? I have both capital and lowercase letters, like `alpha` and `Alpha`.

Comment: @Hristo - is it not possible to distinguish the names another way?  IDs separated only by case are illegal.  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Case_Sensitivity_in_class_and_id_Names).

Comment: There are other ways to distinguish them, this was the easiest at the time so I went with it... didn't think ahead and didn't think OO very well. Thanks!

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll take a look. I tried to de-couple everything as much as possible so that I ca reuse code and I think I got it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.fn.page = function() {
  window.page = this;

  this.symbols = {
    'alpha': ['A',"&#x03B1;"],
    //etc
  }

  this.delegate('div.symbol', 'click', function(event) {
    var div = $(event.target),
        // parse symbol name from class
        symbolClass = $(this).attr('class').replace('symbol',''),
        // fetch map 
        map = page.symbols[symbolClass],
        // replace text
        newText = div.text().replace(map[0],map[1]);
    div.text(newText);    
  });

};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(body).page(); // use the most specific selector that contains all your divs
});
```

Comment: What are you doing here with `delegate()`? Would you mind giving me some comments or an explanation of your idea here?

Comment: Instead of attaching a click handler to each div, you use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) once at the parent level. The parent catches the events and uses the given selector,  e.g. div.symbol, to figure out which function to run.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, I came up with the following code. It doesn't really look at the Symbol class that you mention, but you could easily move the symbols into that as need:

```
var symbols = {
    'alpha': 'a',
    'beta': 'b'
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.symbol').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var classes = $this.attr('class').split(' ');
        $(classes).each(function(ix, cls){
            if(typeof(symbols[cls]) == 'undefined'){ return; }
            $this.html(symbols[cls]);
            return;
        });
    });
});
```

This accounts for using class names and does not fail on unknown classes. Note that I'm using `$.each` instead of `$.click` just as an example. This will behave on each class that it matches, though, so if you have `<div class="symbol alpha beta"></div>` it will work on both alpha and beta!

Code is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/w3ajG/

Answer (score 0):

`var symbols = {'alpha': "&#x03B1;"};` is a better practice, and then u can easily access them like `symbols.alpha` dnt complicate it much,

then

```
var symbols = {
        'alpha': "&#x03B1;",
        'beta' : "&#x03B2;",
};
$('div.symbol.alpha').click(function() {
      //alert(symbols.alpha); // console.debug(symbols.alpha);
      //or
      //alert(symbols['alpha']); // console.debug(symbols['alpha']);
});
```

Comment: I want to refactor this such that my click handler is not specific to a type of symbol... so instead of `$('div.symbol.alpha').click(function() {});`, I want it to be `$('div.symbol').click(function() {});`. How would I set that up with your suggestion?